# Failover not working with Cassandra when using DataStax C# Driver

Tags: c#, azure, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a two node setup in Azure and I am trying to get failover working when connecting with the C# driver. My nodes seem to be communicating fine when working with cqlsh and within OpsCenter.

```
var contact = "publicipforfirstnode";
_cluster = Cassandra.Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint(contact).Build();
_session = _cluster.Connect("demo");
```

I initially connect with the public IP of the first node. This works fine. However in the configuration I use the internal network IPs assigned by my virtual network such as 10.1.0.4, 10.1.0.5, etc. I set them as the listen_address and broadcast_rpc_address for each node. Even though I use the internal IP in the configuration I can connect with the public IP just fine. I have a special firewall rule that allows me to connect from a certain machine on the public IP. However to avoid firewall rules for inner-node communication, I put the nodes on the same virtual network and no extra work is required.

This seems great until my first node goes down. **It then tries the second node using the internal IP.**

> I get an error: All Hosts tried for query (Public IP of First
>   Node), (Internal IP of Second Node)

But since I am connecting from a machine not in the virtual network it can't reach this internal ip. My application won't be in the internal network so this seems like an issue.

Not using internal ips forces me to setup authentication and/or special firewall rules I'd rather not have to do. Is there any way to force the c# driver to use public ips and allow the nodes to communicate on internal ips? Using internal ips seems to be the recommended best practice unless you have multiple regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP configured as `broadcast_rpc_address` in the cassandra.yaml file is used by the drivers to connect to them.

In your case, if you want to connect with the driver using the public ip addresses, you should set the `broadcast_rpc_address` as the public IP address.

You can enable tracing in the driver to see what is happening under the hood:

```
// Specify the minimum trace level you want to see
Cassandra.Diagnostics.CassandraTraceSwitch.Level = TraceLevel.Info;
// Add a standard .NET trace listener
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

[From the docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html):

- listen_address: The IP address or hostname that Cassandra binds to for connecting to other Cassandra nodes.
- broadcast_rpc_address: RPC address to **broadcast** to drivers and other Cassandra nodes. This cannot be set to 0.0.0.0. If blank, it is set to the value of the rpc_address or rpc_interface. If rpc_address or rpc_interfaceis set to 0.0.0.0, this property must be set.

Comment: What's confusing is in the comments it also says the broadcast_rpc_address is used by the other nodes. The broadcast_address also says it's used by the other nodes, so I am thinking they both are. It would be nice if the driver could refer to a different ip address than the internal nodes.

Comment: I understand but in your case you should use `listen_address` for your private ip and `broadcast_rpc_address` for your public ip.

Comment: I tried changing my broadcast_rpc_address and it fixed the failover issue, but I have to see now if the nodes are communicating with each other using the internal ip address since I have the public ip open to everything for testing.

Comment: The edit you posted.. you can see it says "other cassandra nodes" which is the whole problem. I don't want the other cassandra nodes using the public ip address.

Comment: It's how it is broadcasted not how the nodes connect to each other. You should see that the nodes are communicating each other using [nodetool status](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html).

Comment: I recommend you that you enable tracing in the driver to understand what is going on: there wasn't an issue with the failover, the issue was that the driver was never connected to the second node.

Comment: I know that's the issue (with the driver) because it was trying to use the internal IP to connect to the second node which it can't access. Basically I was trying to get the nodes to use the internal IP to communicate but when using the driver I want it to use the public ips. Maybe that's not possible.

Comment: Nodetool status shows the internal ips btw even though broadcast_rpc_address is set to the public ip.

Comment: I ran some tests with the firewall and it worked good. It seems that the nodes are either unaffected by the broadcast_rpc_address (despite the comments) or the fact they happen to be on the internal network using a public IP doesn't matter since it recognizes them as being on the network. Either way this seems like a good solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to understand what `broadcast_address` and `broadcast_rpc_address` mean when your Cassandra cluster is behind a NAT device (like a firewall or gateway).

`broadcast_address` is the address that other nodes **connect** to.  By default, this is the same as `listen_address`(usually you want this because the nodes are in the same network).

In the case where your cluster is across two networks and NAT takes place, you must set it to a value that nodes on both networks can access (like a public IP if you do multi-region deployment in AWS).  This means that traffic within a network, as well as across networks, will go through the NAT device, because the internal IP is not reachable.

`broadcast_rpc_address` is the address that a node "advertizes" about another node.

E.g., node A has `broadcast_address`=10.0.0.100 and `broadcast_rpc_address`=52.2.3.100, node B has `broadcast_address`=10.0.0.101 and `broadcast_rpc_address`=52.2.3.101

What then happens is that node A will connect to node B on 10.0.0.101, but if a client driver asks A "hey, what other nodes are in your cluster?", then it will respond 52.2.3.101 for B.

This design (introduced in Cassandra 2.0.10 I believe) makes it possible for clients outside the network to connect to any node in the cluster (not just the seed nodes).

But a limitation is that you can't have clients both inside and outside the network, otherwise you need to make sure the public IP is reachable both inside and outside the network (like changing firewall settings).

I hope this clarifies things a bit.

### Addition

If you're keen, you can find what a node knows about other nodes with the following `cqlsh` commands:

```
select * from system.peers
```

The `peer` column is the `broadcast_address` of the node, `rpc_address` column is the `broadcast_rpc_address` of the node.

Comment: I believe inter-node communication only uses native and gossip, not rpc, hence `broadcast_rpc_address` is only ever useful for client drivers.  But please correct me if I'm wrong.